# fisrt frame appears green when i write movie with UIImages using AVAssetWriter

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, avfoundation

I Am writing a video using UIImages. I can successfully write  movie.
The problem is that when i play the video it show first few frames as green. 
 Could any one of you help me. I am new to ios.
Thank You

Comment: Did you resolve this issue??

Answer (score 2):

I think the fps (frame per second) of your video will be low. In this case, I think you need not to call CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer. This calling makes the first empty frame and the base green screen is shown.

```
for(UIImage * img in imageArray)
    {
        buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] andSize:size];

        if( frameCount == 0 ) {
          // Please comment out the following line
          //  CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer (NULL, adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &buffer);
        }

        BOOL append_ok = NO;
        int j = 0;
        while (!append_ok && j < 30)
        {
            if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
            {
```